# Existence of entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, entire-functions

Show that there exists an entire function $g(z)$ such that $$g(z)=\frac{\sin(5z)-5\sin(z)}{(z-\pi)^3}$$ for all $z$ $\epsilon$ C\ {$\pi$}

My idea is that since sine functions are entire, and $(z-\pi)^3$ is entire on all $z$ $\epsilon$ C\ {$\pi$}, the function $g(z)$ is entire on all $z$ $\epsilon$ C\ {$\pi$}. I know there's something wrong with my proof but I can't identify where, or think of another approach to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(z):=\frac{\sin(5z)-5\sin(z)}{(z-\pi)^3}$ and show that $\sin(5z)-5\sin(z)$ has at $z=\pi$ a zero of order $3$. Then $f$ has at $z=\pi$ a removable singularity.

Comment: why do we have to show that sin(5z)-5sin(z) has at z=$\pi$ a zeroe of order 3, but not conclude directly that z=$\pi$ is a singular point?

Comment: If $sin(5z)-5sin(z) $ has at $ z=\pi$ a zero of order 3, then there is an entire function $h$ with  $sin(5z)-5sin(z) =(z- \pi)^3g(z)$ and $g(\pi) \ne 0$. It follows that $g(z)=\frac{sin(5z)-5sin(z)}{(z- \pi)^3}$

Answer (score 1):

*May be a way to approach the problem.*

If you use $$\sin(5x)=5\sin(x)-2\sin^3(x)+16\sin^5(x)$$ then $$\sin(5x)-5\sin(x)=-2\sin^3(x)+16\sin^5(x)=-2\sin^3(x)(1-8\sin^2(x))$$